# Share score on facebook

Tags: javascript

I have a application with few pictures and when user check a picture, he gets a +1 score. I display the total score on page with this code:

```
total score: <span id="perk1"></span>
```

my script is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    var actor=0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#perk1').html(actor);

        $("#img100").click(function() {
            if($('#img100').is(':checked'))
                actor=actor+1;
            else if(actor>0)
                actor=actor-1;
            $('#perk1').html(actor);
        });

        $("#img95").click(function() {
            if($('#img95').is(':checked'))
                actor=actor+1;
            else if(actor>0)
                actor=actor-1;
            $('#perk1').html(actor);
        });

    });


});//]]>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="imgs">

<div class="thumb">
<label for="img100"><img src="priyanka_chopra\gunday.jpg" height="200" width="275"/></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="img100" name="img100" value="0" />
<label for="img95"><img src="priyanka_chopra\krrish3.jpg" height="200" width="275"/></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="img95" name="img95" value="0" />

</div>
```

Everything works fine. Now i want a share to facebook button which can publish my score on facebook. I was able to share the whole page to facebook but it will show score as 0. I want my score to be saved and then display in facebook as a dialog box or full html page.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass points like get parameter or hash,
for example

http://example.com/?points=10

http://example.com/#10

and then just get them on document load in js, or just if you use php just get this parameter and generate page with points.

Comment: the example pages are not showing any code ie http://example.com/?points=10 just opens a page with text-"Example text".

Comment: @user3388005 i mean it just example of url format at your site, instead of example.com there should be your domain url.